# How much power does a wrist watch use to function?

Tags: batteries, watts

I am wondering how some watches last for a year or more on battery.
How many watts does a typical battery powered watch use to move the hands?

Comment: find the watch battery code you are interested in, find it's voltage and capacity (in milliamp hours) and estimate the power drain over a year (~8765 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having a wristwatch handy, I wound my pocket watch to check.

I had to apply a torque measured at 0.04Nm to the key, and rotate it 4 full turns (8*Pi radians) to run it for a day. This works out as 0.04 * 8 * Pi Newton-metres, or 1 joule. This lasts for 24 hours or 86400 seconds.

Thus a verge escapement fusee pocketwatch made in 1841 consumes 11.6 microwatts.

Comment: wow that's very Impressive

Comment: I should add that most of the power goes into the balance wheel (the high-Q resonator), probably less than 10% or 1 uW is spent moving the hands.

Comment: I'd like to see that torque wrench.